# PHP AJAX Form Submit displaying Array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, forms

When I submit my form to post a comment on my page the page displays the array of data and does not just display the page with the comment fading in.

This is what i see in my browser after i hit the submit button (the record gets inserted fine):

```
{"streamid":1567,"cm":{"id":"0","avatar":"uploads\/30-av.jpg","name":"Mike<\/a>","content":"blah blah blah","time":"some seconds ago"}}
```

PHP

```
$action = $_GET['action'];
if ($action == 'blasting') {
$blast = input($_POST['blast']);
if ($blast AND strlen($blast) > 1) {
    $stm = $_DB->prepare('insert into wl_activity (user_id, action, posted_on, data) values (?, ?, ?, ?)');
    $stm->execute(array($_USER->get_user_id(), 'blast', time(), $blast));
    }
echo json_encode($array);
   }
```

My Form code

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajaxupload.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/newsfeed.js"></script>

 <form method="post" action="index.php?cmd=ajax&action=blasting" id="blast-form">
            <textarea class="form_input" id="blastbox" name="blast" style="width:90%" ></textarea>
            <input type="submit" id="blastbtn" value="Post" class="form_submit" />

<div id="ajax-feed"></div>

    <?php $general = array(); ?>
    <?php
        foreach ($feeds as $f) {
            if ($f['action'] == 'blast')
                array_push($general, 'blast');
                //unset($general[count($general)-1]);
            else
                array_push($general, 'normal');
        }
    ?>
```

Here is my jquery.form.js http://pastebin.com/MP3uVdcP
Here is my newsfeed.js that http://pastebin.com/ymSNjXJR

Comment: you say the problem is in browser but all the code you provided is server code, where's the javascript? You are returning json object.. what were you expecting?

Comment: Well this code was on another site that I purchased and on that site as you hit submit the comment would appear on the site directly before your eyes, with no page refresh. I'm a complete noob here I will add all the files I am working with to pastebin and update the post one moment.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is just a simple form with no Ajax functionality attached (as far as we can see in your example).

Your browser is successfully posting the form by moving to `index.php?cmd=ajax&action=blasting`, which is where you see your JSON response.

You need to use JavaScript to hook into the form submission event, stop the default action (moving to the next page) and send it using Ajax.

Here is an example:

```
$("#blast-form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).action, $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
        $('#ajax-feed').html(response);
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay, Yeah I found this in another page its similar.. ` var v = $('#blast-form').validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit(options);
        }
    });`

Comment: Good , submitHandler function of Validate prevent event to submit

Comment: @iJD What do I need to modify? Sorry I'm not too familiar with this.

Comment: Alex can you take a quick look at my JS and nudge me in the right direction as far as what to modify? http://pastebin.com/ymSNjXJR

Comment: @kcray when you use a validate and it do the postback (no ajax) its cause for error in submitHandler, use the firebug on console tab and preserve the log for view you error.